# CSS Ipad safari margin not working media query

Tags: android, html, ios, css, ipad

Hey I'm having a problem with a wordpress site I'm working and for some reason the logo doesn't margin to the left on the safari for the Ipad.  The media query I added doesn't effect the logo change in portrait view. It works fine with android devices and all other devices except IPAD,Can someone please help here's the link to the site, Thanks really appreciate yet.

link: [www.annesub17.com](http://annesub17.com)

here's the code

```
@media (max-width: 999px){
.logo {
margin-left: -17px;
 }
}
```

Comment: Actually i found out that i had to move it even more to the left for portrait view on the Ipad? can anyone tell me what that is ? i had to move it -50 pixels to show it correctly on the ipad but for everything else it was correct. Can anyone help explain this to me ?